# Can I remake an old game? I do not want to sell it

Tags: game-design, copyright, video

Im gonna remake an **old** video game that was for play station 1
And when i done it i wanna create a video about game and gameplay and Construction steps and upload it to YouTube

If i put download link into description and upload video i get copyright strike?
Or if i just upload video and dont share the game i get copyright strike too?
And another question
can i **monetize** my videos  ?

Comment: Are you using assets (art, graphics, music/ sound effects, code) directly from the original game or did you recreate it? Are you planning to use the exact same name of the game?

Comment: Remember to search for your question before posting a new one. [Searching for "remake" leads to existing answers to this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=remake). For questions about the legality/TOS-compliance of what you can post on YouTube, you may want to ask on a video-related site like the [Video Production StackExchange](https://video.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Byoutube%5D+legal), as that's not strictly within our purview of game development.